# SQLSyntaxErrorException when deploying Spring Boot app to Heroku

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot app to Heroku. It uses a remote database which is provided by [RemoteMysl](https://remotemysql.com). However, when the app is building, it creates all tables in the database except one table. I am getting the following error on Heroku Application Log.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'groups (id) on delete
>   cascade' at line 1

**Group model**

```java
package com.itsfive.back.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.itsfive.back.model.audit.DateAudit;

@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group extends DateAudit{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 30)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 160)
    private String description;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by_id", nullable = false)
    private User created_by;    

    private String coverPhoto;

    public User getCreated_by() {
        return created_by;
    }

    public void setCreated_by(User created_by) {
        this.created_by = created_by;
    }

    public String getCoverPhoto() {
        return coverPhoto;
    }

    public void setCoverPhoto(String coverPhoto) {
        this.coverPhoto = coverPhoto;
    }

    public Group(@NotBlank @Size(max = 30) String name, @Size(max = 160) String description,User created_by) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.created_by = created_by;
    }

    public Group() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String groupName) {
        this.name = groupName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public User getCreatedBy() {
        return created_by;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(User user) {
        this.created_by = user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you are using Mysql 8.0 then this issue is due you are using `Mysql` reserved keywords like is `groups` on your table name.

You can take a look [SQL reserved words for Mysql 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) then you have two options

1.- Rename `groups` table to `users_group` or table name that you want.

```
@Table(name = "users_group")
public class Group extends XXXXX { ... }
```

2.- Force to use `groups` table name.

If you are using JPA, you can escape with double quotes:

```
    @Table(name = "\"groups\"")
    public class Group extends XXXXX { ... }
```

If you're using Hibernate native API, then you can escape them using backticks:

```
    @Table(name =  "`groups`")
    public class Group extends XXXXX { ... }
```